Пропадает база данных в DBeaver после перезагрузки
Я создала подключение в DBeaver к PostgreSQL который у меня работает через Open Server Panel и создала базу данных, но после перезагрузки подключения созданная мною база данных пропадает, хотя в shell PostgreSQL база данных отображается. Так же я пыталась создать базу данных MySQL которая так же у меня стоит через Open Server Panel база данных создается и после перезагрузки остается на месте. Как исправить данную проблему?

Поправьте заголовок, а то звучит не очень....

Знакомый мне разработчик из DBeaver говорит примерно такое: "Найдите в настройках соединения опцию show all databases и всё заработает"

установила эту настройку не помогло

Попробуйте вот тут спросить: https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver
